# AMD Radeon 7800 series second DVI does not work

Tags: amd-radeon, dvi, amd-graphics-card

I have a Radeon 7800 series and it has 4 ports on the back: 2x DVI, 1x DisplayPort, 1x Hdmi. I have 2 Asus 27" 60hz monitors and an asus 24" 144hz monitor.

I just got the new 144hz monitor and would like to have all of my monitors work together off of the same card.  Before I got the 144hz monitor, I had my left side asus hooked to HDMI, the right side asus was hooked to DVI (DVI-D Single Link cable).  This worked great!

I now want to put the 24" 144hz monitor in between these two older monitors.  I moved the right side asus' DVI cable to the second DVI slot on the back of the card and plugged in the 144hz monitor with a DVI-D Dual Link cable.  Only the HDMI monitor and 144hz monitor work.

If I unplug any other monitor, the third monitor turns on.  So it seems I can only have 2 monitors on at a single time.

In my display settings, I see a third monitor and I'm able to select the option to extend my display to that monitor, but when I do, I'm not able to select a resolution and I get an error saying "the display settings could not be saved. Please try a different combination of display settings"

The funny thing is; when I restart the computer, this elusive monitor shows a boot screen.

Is this extra dvi port made for such instances? Am I able to "activate" this port? I've ordered a DisplayPort cable for the monitor, but I'd like to know why this port won't work.

**I've updated the question above with more information**

Comment: Take a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface and see if you're using the wrong cable or interface for your monitor/card combination

Comment: @jatuttle0, Thanks to that article, I've found out that I'm using a DVI-D (Single Link) cable.  Now, I just need to find out what this extra port needs.  This monitor worked when it was plugged in where the 144hz monitor is now plugged in with the same cable.  Would there be 2 different DVI ports on the back of one card?

Comment: It's not only possible, it's pretty typical in mid-range cards. Look at the ports on both monitor and card then compare that to the cable you're using.

Comment: @jatuttle0 The top port has the extra squares around the dash (DVI-I Dual Link) and the bottom port has does not have those (DVI-D Dual Link).  Even if I switch the cables around on each port, I still do not have access of one of the monitors.  I believe there's some sort of eyefinity setting that's not turned on (but of course the newest AMD drivers won't allow me to open settings anymore after I just updated).

Comment: Just got the display port cable.  It all works now.